Notation for class that implements certain interface
I have this interface:
interface DataAdapterInterface {
    init(url: string): void
    execute(command: string, values?: string[]): Promise<any>
    insert(items: any[]): Promise<any>
    find(items: any[]): Promise<any>
    update(items: any[]): Promise<boolean>
    remove(items: any[]): Promise<boolean>
}

and also a simple function for decoration:
export function protocol(protocol: string) {
    return function (constructor: Function) {
        constructor['__protocol'] = protocol;
    };
}

then I made a class implementing this interface:
@protocol("mysql")
export class MySQLAdapter implements DataAdapterInterface {
    init(url: string): void {}
    execute(command: string): Promise<any> {}
    insert(item: any[]): Promise<any> {}
    find(item: any[]): Promise<any> {}
    update(item: any[]): Promise<boolean> {}
    remove(item: any[]): Promise<boolean> {}
}

and I have this function, that receive the said class.
export function register(adapter: DataAdapterInterface) { 
    ConnectionFactory.register(adapter['__protocol'], adapter)
}

Now, I got an error noting that MySqlAdapter is not DataAdapterInterface when I do this:
register(MySQLAdapter);

The JavaScript runs fine without problem, and if I put any as parameter, the TypeScript compiler would be completed without error. But I want to limit the parameter to only class that implements DataAdapterInterface.
Is there a way, to pass MySQLAdapter class as a parameter, without making an instance to it other than any type?

So, to clarify: your question is how come MySQLAdapter doesn't implement DataAdapterInterface?

As I understand it from the error message, to conform to adapter: DataAdapterInterface I have to pass as register(new MySQLAdapter). But I want to pass it as register(MySQLAdapter)

This does seem to be a duplicate and you're looking for new () => DataAdapterInterface s the type instead of just DataAdapterInterface. If that does not turn out to be what you want, please [edit] the question to clarify, and while you're doing so, make the code a [mre] where we can all copy and paste it into our own IDEs to see the issue without distractions like undeclared things (KeyValue, etc) or unimplemented methods, etc.

@jcalz ah.. yes.. Thank you. Its a duplicate
